# Ubuntu 14.04 Skype 4.3 volume too low

Tags: 14.04, sound, skype

The Skype volume on my internal speaker was fine for a while but suddenly went very low.  It is still usable but only in a quite room.

The only internal Skype sound settings is "sound devices" where I can play a test sound (yea very low).   Also, "allow skype to adjust my mixer levels" does not make a difference.  Ubuntu's sound test is at full volume.

I'm not sure what changed.  The typical "output volume" in the toolbar can be moved above 100% and helps without distortion.  The `alsamixer` volumes are maximized.  I found some channels in `alsamixer` under the sound device `1  HDA Intel PCH`.  There are no extra channels that need to be adjusted, I tried them all.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC255 Analog [ALC255 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

lspci
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 48)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] (rev ff)

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f3:2098 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:5754 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

uname -a
Linux jcalfee-Inspiron-7548 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You did check Skype's internal volume settings, too, right?

Comment: The only internal Skype sound settings is "sound devices" where I can play a test sound (yea very low).   Ubuntu's sound test is at full volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Call the skype `Echo / Sound test service` (callto://echo123)
2. Go to system menu in the the top-right corner:

   [image: Gear icon]
3. Click <kbd>System Settings</kbd> and then <kbd>Sound</kbd>
4. Click the <kbd>Applications</kbd> tab
5. As you're still in a call with Skype, you'll see the Skype volume.
6. Adjust to your needs (including >100%)

### Done!  :-)

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: What is the `]` behind the image?

Comment: Oh...  It's a mistake of the UI when inserting stuff...  I should take this up on [meta.se]...